# how to scroll extjs 4 grid horizontally

Tags: extjs4

What is the proper way to scroll a grid horizontally on load.

I want to scroll to a particular grid column on load.

I can focus the column I want using this:

```
dataStore.on('load', function() {
     var cl = dataGrid.columns[43];
     cl.focus();
});
```

but the grid does not scroll when I do this.

Comment: the main issue turned out to be the fact that I had a 'locked' column, kudos to @Lolo for providing a jsfiddle, it enabled me to locate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to use `scrollByDeltaX`. Example:

```
viewready: function(){
    var c = this.columns[5];
    var p = c.getPosition();

    this.scrollByDeltaX(p[0]);
}
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/YRraU/2/